# How do I use python version 3.7.1 in Kaggle

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, kaggle

I'm trying to train a tensorflow ML model scripted in python version 3.7.1. However the python version in kaggle is 3.10.2. Is there any method through which I can use a python 3.7 environment and is it possible to make it the default env?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any method through which I can use a python 3.7 environment

Yes,you can change the python version in Kaggle.
you can follow these [link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/blinkthink/change-python-version-on-kaggle)
for steps and commands.

Please note that the availability of specific Python versions may vary, and you should check the Kaggle environment settings for the most up-to-date information.
Additionally, keep in mind that using an older Python version may limit access to some libraries or features that are available in newer Python versions.